# Naming the output layer created by a QGIS 'Feature filter'

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-modeler

When using the 'Feature filter' within the Model Designer of QGIS (v. 3.16.10), if a filter is set to 'Final Output', the layer name is prefixed with 'OUTPUT_' e.g. if the Output Name of the filter is 'Woodland', the name of the layer that is added is 'OUTPUT_Woodland'. Is there a way to prevent this prefix being added?

---

Edit: It's raised as an issue here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/45689

Comment: It doesn't address your issue directly, but you could use the Rename Layer tool afterwards and have its output set to 'Final Output'.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. AFAIK the Rename Layer tool only works on layers that already exist in the project? So don't think it would be able to rename a layer that's created as part of the model. Tried it just now, and set the 'Feature filter' as a dependency within the 'Rename layer', but no luck.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While the prefix is always added by default, you can just edit the resulting green output node and remove it there.